# apa6 documentclass splitting reference section between columns

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, two-column, apa6

I am new to this community, apologies if this is a very basic question.

I have been writing a paper in APA6 and have been using natbib, and a corresponding bib file.  When the reference section is compiled in the paper, the text is interrupted mid-reference and put to the second column.  Is there a way of disabling this?  References are instantiated with this

```
\bibliography{references}
\nocite{*}
```

and come out like this:

[image]

and I wish they would print in one column, sort of like this (apologies for the shadows, on a time crunch)

[image]

I do understand that this is visually minimized with more references, but this is for a very casual and small writing assignment where I will only need to use 2 references, so this error looks terrible.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. For future questions it's really helpful to provide a small compilable document that demonstrates your problem. This will make it much easier for people to help you without guessing at the code you're using to produce the problem. For your question, a document like the one in my answer (minus the solution of course) would have been ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlanMunn !  I will be sure to do this in the future, and I'll edit my answer soon to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apa6` document class loads the `flushend` package to balance columns. You can issue a `\raggedend` command just before the `\bibliography{...}` command to unbalance the last page.

```
\documentclass[jou,natbib]{apa6}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Chomsky1965,
    address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    author = {Noam Chomsky},
    publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\shorttitle{Title}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\citet{Chomsky1965}
\clearpage
\raggedend
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]